# Performing operations on a List<> created from ICollection objects - ICollection objects are being changed

Tags: c#, list, icollection

I'm trying to create a string with parts and quantities made from data contained in an ICollection.  I'm using a List to build the totals I need but when I perform operations on this List it's actually changing the values in the ICollection.  I don't want those values changed.  Code follows.  PartsUsed is the ICollection.  Is this because adding individual members of the collection to the list is only pointing to the original data?

```
private string PartsDetails(out int totalCount, String modtype)
    {

        totalCount = 0;
        var str = new StringBuilder();
        var usedParts = new List<PartUsed>();
        var indexnum = 0;


        foreach (var u in Rma.AssociatedUnits)
        {
            if (u.PartsUsed != null && u.PartsUsed.Count > 0)
            {
                if ((modtype == "ALL"))
                {
                    foreach (var rep in u.PartsUsed)
                    {
                        if (!usedParts.Exists(x => x.Repair.Name == rep.Repair.Name))
                        {
                            usedParts.Add(rep);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            usedParts[usedParts.FindIndex(f => f.Repair.Name == rep.Repair.Name)].RepairPartQuantity += rep.RepairPartQuantity;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (var partsGroup in usedParts)
        {
            str.AppendFormat(str.Length > 0 ? Environment.NewLine + "{0} - {1}" : "{0} - {1}", partsGroup.RepairPartQuantity, partsGroup.Repair.Name);
            totalCount += partsGroup.RepairPartQuantity;
        }

        return str.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: what is the `ICollection` in the code?it's `u.PartsUsed`?

Comment: Yes, u.PartsUsed is the ICollection.

Comment: you need to create a new instance of object ``PartUsed`` and add it to ``usedParts`` to avoid this, because the `rep` in  `usedParts` is just a copy of `rep` in `u.PartsUsed`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your `PartUsed` is a class(e.g. [reference type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types)), so `u.PartsUsed` is actually a collection of references to some objects, so `usedParts.Add(rep)` is actually adding the same reference(object) to `usedParts` and when you get and modify one of them in `usedParts[usedParts.FindIndex(f => f.Repair.Name == rep.Repair.Name)].RepairPartQuantity += rep.RepairPartQuantity` you are actually modifying shared instance. This behavior can be demonstrated like this also:

```
class MyClass { public int Prop { get; set; }   }

var ref1 = new MyClass{Prop = 1};
var ref2 = ref1;
ref2.Prop = 2;
Console.WriteLine(ref2.Prop);// prints 2
```

One way around would be to create a clone of `PartUsed` to put into `usedParts` but in your particular case it seems that you can use `Dictionary<string, int>`(assuming `RepairPartQuantity` is `int`) for `usedParts`. Something like this:

```
var usedParts = new Dictionary<string, int>();

.....
foreach (var rep in u.PartsUsed)
{
      if (!usedParts.ContainsKey(rep.Repair.Name))
      {
          usedParts[rep.Repair.Name] = rep.RepairPartQuantity;
      }
      else
      {
          usedParts[rep.Repair.Name] += rep.RepairPartQuantity;
      }
}

foreach (var kvp in usedParts)
    {
        str.AppendFormat(str.Length > 0 ? Environment.NewLine + "{0} - {1}" : "{0} - {1}", kvp.Value, kvp.Key);
        totalCount += kvp.Value;
    }
```

Comment: That fixed the issue.  Thanks for taking the time to look at it, I appreciate it.

Comment: @BigBear2k was glad to help!